# Is it possible to have a script be both a MonoBehaviour and an Interface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class that needs to be an interface, but i'd also like it to track time using the update function. I know I can handle the time in a separate class that just calls the interface class but I'm wondering if it is possible to combine the two.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a _abstract class_. What characteristics of interfaces do you need?

Comment: What is your goal? What is it that you are trying to do? No, don't tell me how you are writing the code, tell me what you want the behavior to be.

Comment: you have a interface , and that interface have `Update()` function ?

Comment: A class cannot “be” an interface, because it’s a class. There’s no reason why a MonoBehaviour couldn’t implement an interface though. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending [Draco18s' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504358/7111561) I guess what you wanted to ask is:

Can a `class` that **inherits** from `MonoBehaviour` also **implement** an [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)? - Well of course! That's the whole idea of having [interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/index): A class can only inherit from exactly **one** parent class type. Interfaces, however, enable a class to "inherit" multiple sets of methods. The classic example:

There is a parent type `Boat`.
Then there are inherited types: `SailBoat : Boat` and `MotorBoat : Boat`.
Now what do you do if you want a `SailBoat` that also has a motor? Instead of defining everything twice you create interfaces `ISailBoat` and `IMotorBoat` and create a new class and let it implement both interfaces `MotorSailBoat : Boat, ISailBoat, IMotorBoat`.

Advantage: This type can now be used as both `ISailBoat` or `IMotorBoat` for example it can appear in lists of both types.

#### Create Interface based on existing class

Can I convert an existing `MonoBehaviour` class to an interface? - Well let's say you have a class

```
public class AnAwesomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void DoSomethingAwesome()
    {
        Debug.Log("Are you not entertained!?");
    }
}
```

So to make that an interface is simply create a new interface with the according method signatures

```
interface IMyAwesomeInterface
{
    // interface methods are automatically PUBLIC
    void DoSomethingAwesome();
}
```

and let your `MonoBehaviour` implement that interface.

```
public class AnAwesomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, IMyAwesomeInterface
{
    public void DoSomethingAwesome()
    {
        Debug.Log("Are you not entertained!?");
    }
}
```

You don't have to change nothing else in your original class but can now use the same interface also for other classes.

---

#### Inheritance

If you rather have your original `class` and simply want to **extend** it with **additional** methods but still being able to **also use the original on**e ... well that's what's called [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance):

```
public class AnAwesomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void DoSomethingAwesome()
    {
        Debug.Log("Are you not entertained!?");
    }
}

public class AnEvenMoreAwesomeBehaviour : AnAwesomeBehaviour 
{
    public void DoSomethingAwesomeButWithParamters(string horse)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Look at my {horse}, my {horse} is amazing!");
    }
}
```

This new class `AnEvenMoreAwesomeBehaviour` can now do both `DoSomethingAwesome` (which it inherited) and `DoSomethingAwesomeButWithParamters(string)` which it implemented.

---

#### Abstract class

Finally you kind of have a "combination" of both in an [`abstract class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract). Such a class is just a template and **never instantiated** itself. You can however inherit from it and create new classes based on its functionalities:

```
// inherits from MonoBehaviour -> already implements the full functionality
// of MonoBehaviors
public abstract class AnAwesomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    // it can have some fields all inheritors shall have
    // everyone will have access to this
    public string Horse;

    // only this class and inheritors will have access to this
    protected int amountOfHorses;

    // only this class has access to this
    private Camera _camera;


    // The same can be done for methods
    // But there are now special methods

    // a virtual method already has its own implementation
    // but can be overwritten or extended by inheritors
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        _camera = Camera.main;

        Debug.Log("On Start I usually do nothing special with the " + _camera.name);
    } 

    // an abstract method kind of works like an interface
    // every inheritor HAS TO implement this method exactly with the same 
    // signature
    public abstract void DoYourThing(string value);

    // and you still can implement some default behaviours that every
    // inheritor will just do
    private void Update()
    {
        // rotate the object forever
        transform.Rotate(0, Time.deltaTime * 45, 0);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this abstract template and create your classes from it

```
public class AnAwesomeCountBehaviour : AnAwesomeBehaviour 
{
    // I have to implement this
    public override void DoYourThing(string value)
    {
        Horse = value;
        Debug.Log($"Look I now have {amountOfHorses} {Horse}" + (amountOfHorses == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    }

    // and optionally CAN extend or overwrite this
    protected override void Start()
    {
        //also optional first execute whatever the original implementation does
        base.Start();

        // now add my own stuff
        Debug.Log($"First I had {amountOfHorses} {Horse}" + (amountOfHorses == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    }
}
```

Note: [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) methods could also be used in a non-abstract class while `abstract` can **only** be used in an abstract class.

Answer (score -1):

## Direct answer: no

MonoBehavior is a class. A piece of code can not both BE an interface AND extend a class.

## Indirect answer: also no

If you want a piece of code to *do something* ("track time using the update function") then it is not an interface (or an abstract class (sorta)).